# Download m3u8 juicycode using python

Tags: python-3.x, video-streaming, m3u8

I am trying to download the video playing in the browser, I am able to get the m3u8 url using selenium. These urls show in the network tab in developer tools -

[image: Developer tools]

When I try to access the url in the browser or via python I get 404 Not found or "http.client.RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response" but the video plays fine in the browser and the following parts start getting downloaded -

[image: Video being downloaded]

How do I download the video?